# self.userUid = user.user.uid method still not working in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Ok so in my code I get this error:'Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'uid''. Even after trying to use the authDataResult or the self.userUid = user.user.uid, I'm still getting the error. Here's my code if anyone wants to help me

```
@IBAction func SignIn (_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {

            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

                if error == nil {

                    self.userUid = user.user.uid

                    KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.userUid, forKey: "uid")

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMessages", sender: nil)
                } else {

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSignUp", sender: nil)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Thanks if you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `if error == nil {` do the following :

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
if let user = user {
  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project.
  // Do NOT use this value to authenticate with your backend server,
  // if you have one. Use getTokenWithCompletion:completion: instead.
  let uid = user.uid
  let email = user.email
}
```

You can find more information here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users

Comment: After doing it I'm getting: 'Value of type 'AuthDataResult?' has no member 'uid'' and 'Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'uid''